# Attempting to convert an image to grayscale, or better, binary

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing

My basic plan here is to create an image recognition software that tracks the size of different bubbles. I basically have a compilation of pictures that constitute a video. I have it working as of right now using PIMS to import the files I need and place them into an array (rawframes). I can print my picture.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

import pims
from pims import pipeline
import trackpy as tp
import os

import matplotlib  as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

@pipeline
def binary(frame):
    return frame[:, :, 1]

id_example = 1
rawframes = pims.ImageSequence(os.path.join('BubbleSize/90FoamQuality/DryFoams', 'T20190411_002_ (*).jpg'), process_func=binary)
plt.imshow(rawframes[id_example])
```

What I am trying to do here is convert the images from regular into black and white. I have not used many of the things I imported yet I know, this is a very preliminary step.

However, below is a before and after image comparison. Can someone help me out or walk me through these steps here? I get lost when it comes to filtering the images through python.

[image: Before Code]
[image: After Code]

---

edit --> when I change my pipeline function to the below, I get the same green image

[image: pipeline_new]

---

edit2 --> printing frame.shape and frame.dtype in binary pipeline respectively
[image: shape_type]

Comment: There seem to be 2 results? Is there something wrong with them? Why are they different? Did you maybe forget to set the matplotlib colourmap to grey `cmap='gray'`?

Comment: Your method of converting to greyscale appears to be just taking the Green channel? Normally you would take a proportion of each of the R, G and B channels.

Comment: I fixed the OP to make description of the images more clear. If I set matplotlib to plot only gray, then that wouldn't alter the image array itself correct? Also, I have tried using a proportion but received the same green image oddly. I will retry that.

Comment: I plan to implement an image tracking software on each of the bubbles and record their respective changes in size over time. I assumed a grayscale/binary image would be easier to track accurately.

Comment: I am not at all familiar with `pims` so other folk may be able to help you better. As a start, I would print `frame.shape` and `frame.dtype` in your `binary` function to get a better idea of the size and type of your images.

Comment: Pay attention to what Mark said in the very first comment: add `cmap='gray'` to your `plt.imshow` command. You see colors because pyplot uses a colormap to show gray-value images. Each gray level is mapped to a color in the display.

Comment: Ok thanks guys. That worked, I was about to switch over to opencv.